# Reject results in BigQuery

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

I have a code that execute a query using a job. If the query takes more than 5 minutes to complete, I need to reject these results. Is there any way to reject the query results?

This is my code:

```
while (true)
{
    Job pollJob = s.Jobs.Get(projectId, jobId.JobId).Execute();
    elapsedTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks - startTime;
    if (pollJob.Status.State.Equals("DONE")) return "OK";
    else if (DateTime.Now > minutes5) {
          //I don't want that the results are append in the table
    }
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery doesn't yet support explicit job cancelling, though it is tracked as a feature request.  See https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=97

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're appending the query results to a table. One option would be to write the results to a different temporary location and then copying the temp table with append to your results table. That is, if your destination table is dataset.results, you could write the query results to dataset_temp.temp_results. If the query that created temp_results completed quickly enough, you could append it to the dataset.results table via copy operation and the write_append write disposition.

You'd have a couple of options for the temp table. You could create new tables every time but specify an expiration time so they get cleaned up automatically. Or you could overwrite them each time with write_truncate write disposition, so they would always have exactly one time slice worth of data.

Comment: Yes, I'm appending the query results to a table. The first option sounds good but, Could you assert that copy operation gets me a stable response time?